# Why to specify java version in maven build?

Tags: java, maven

When I was building my project like :-

`mvn clean install -DskipTests`

, then it was giving some error.

After that, I just added, -Djdk.version=1.8, then it works fine.

Can someone tell what is the reason for this?

Comment: Post your `pom.xml` file. Most likely you are missing the `maven-compiler-plugin` and it defaults to Java 5.

Comment: Also, for the future - "some error" is literally trying to tell you what is wrong. Tell it to people you try to get help from.

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this in your pom:

```
    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.3</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>1.8</source>
                        <target>1.8</target>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
       ....
    </build>
```

Answer (score 2):

It may be because you might be missing the `maven-compiler-plugin`.

Try the following:

```
<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
   ....
</build>
```

From Maven 3, it defaults to `JDK 1.5`. So if you do not include the version, it will take `JDK 1.5` as default compiler version.

Since, you mentioned that you used `JDK 1.8`, and the error disappeared. So if you had `maven-compiler-version` defined in the `pom.xml`, the error might be because the version would had not been defined.

So by default, it pointed to `JDK 1.5` and it was trying to compile the code which would be defined for `JDK 1.8` and not for `JDK 1.5`.

So, it is better to define the correct java version in the `pom.xml`

Answer (score 1):

> Why to specify java version in maven build?

Because Maven won't try to guess the Java version your project was created with (the one you probably only configured in your IDE).

You need to specify the earliest version supported in your `pom.xml` with:

```
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```